# How to display value on dropdown menu based on selected data/ id?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Below is my code on how to print or display one data from an array on the dropdown menu. The data is stored in the API. I use for loop for my code. However, when I run using below's code, it displays more than one dropdown box. I already searched for the solution but still, it didn't solve my problem. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<div class="select" id="new-input" onselect="SelectStudents()"> 
<?php $i = 0; foreach ($arr['data'] as $key => $value) { ?> 
   <select required="<?php echo ($i == 0) ? 'required':''; ?>"> 
      <option value="<?php echo $value['studentName']; ?>">
         <?php echo $value['studentName']; ?>
      </option> 
   </select> 
<?php $i++; } ?>
</div>




// Data From API
"data": [
    {
        "TeacherID": "123",
        "TeacherName": "Miss Sara",
        "StudName": "Nina Simon",
    },
    {
        "TeacherID": "124",
        "TeacherName": "Madam Downy",
        "StudName": "Mike Dave",
    },
    {
        "TeacherID": "125",
        "TeacherName": "Mr. Adam",
        "StudName": "Jenny William",
    }
]
```

[I expect  if I click Miss Sara from the menu, it will load students' name under Miss Sara (which is Nina Simon) on dropdown menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY8kV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<select>` tag is inside the loop so the code produces a select element for each iteration of the loop.

Try this:

```
<div class="select" id="new-input" onselect="SelectStudents()"> 

  <select required> 

    <?php foreach ($arr['data'] as $key => $value) { 

        echo '<option value="'.$value['studentName'].'">';
        echo       $value['studentName'];
        echo '</option>';

    } ?>  

  </select>

</div>
```

As far as changing DOM elements on list select: it is probably better to use JavaScript. But if you have to do it serverside, here is an idea for a function you can use to help you:

```
function getStudents($teacherID, $arr) {
  foreach ($arr as $key => $record) { 
    if ($record['TeacherID'] == $teacherID){
        return $record['StudName'];
    }
  }
}
```

> I expect if I click Miss Sara from the menu, it will load students' name under Miss Sara (which is Nina Simon) on dropdown menu.

So based on my understanding, you want something like this.
 - I have used some assumptions about what's going on.
 - I hardcoded data as a php variable.
 - The original question was about foreach loop, so I used those a lot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style type="text/css">
    a{
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    .card{
      padding: 1rem;
      background-color: #eee;
      width: 300px;
    }
    select{
      margin-top: 1rem;
      width: 300px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php

  class StudentsClass
  {

    public function listStudents($teacherID, $arr) {
      foreach ($arr as $key => $record) { 
        if ($record['TeacherID'] == $teacherID){
            return $record['StudName'];
        }
      }
    }

    public function listTeachers($arr) {
      $s=[];
      foreach ($arr as $key => $record) { 
        $s[$record['TeacherID']] = $record['TeacherName'];
      }
      return $s;
    }
  }


  class DisplayHTML
  {


    public function selectHTML($list,$cssClass='') {
      $s='';
      if ($cssClass!='') $css = 'class="'.$cssClass.'" ' ; else $css = '';

      foreach ($list as $key => $item) { 
        $s.='<option '.$css.'value="'.$item.'">'.$item.'</option>';
      }
      $s = '<select>'.$s.'</select>';
      return $s;
    }

    public function anchorHTML($list,$cssClass='') {
      $s='';
      if ($cssClass!='') $css = 'class="'.$cssClass.'" ' ; else $css = '';
      foreach ($list as $key => $item) { 
        $s.='<a '.$css.'href="?teacherID='.$key.'">'.$item.'</a>';
      }
      return $s;
    }

    public function divHTML($id,$data) {
      $s='<div class="card"> <h2>My Student list</h2><ul id="studentlist"> </ul>';
      foreach ($data as $key => $item) { 
        if ($item['TeacherID']==$id){
          foreach ($item['StudName'] as $k => $value) {
            $s.='<li>'.$value.'</li>';
          }
          $s.='<h3>'.$item['TeacherName'].'</h3></div>';
          return $s;
        }
      }
      return '<div class="card">
        <h2>My Student list</h2><ul><li>-</li></ul>
        <h3>--</h3> </div>';
    }

  }


  $arr =  [
    [
        "TeacherID"=> "123",
        "TeacherName"=> "Miss Sara",
        "StudName"=> ["Nina","Simon"],
    ],
    [
        "TeacherID"=> "124",
        "TeacherName"=> "Madam Downy",
        "StudName"=> ["Mike","Dave"],
    ],
    [
        "TeacherID"=> "125",
        "TeacherName"=> "Mr. Adam",
        "StudName"=> ["Jenny","William"],
    ]
  ];



  $stlst = new DisplayHTML;
  $stdents = new StudentsClass;

  echo $stlst->anchorHTML($stdents->listTeachers($arr));
  if (isset($_GET['teacherID'])) {
    echo $stlst->divHTML($_GET['teacherID'],$arr);
    echo $stlst->selectHTML($stdents->listStudents($_GET['teacherID'],$arr));
  }


  ?>  


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used your javascript method, however it's not working for me. For the PHP one, I used your answer also and it listed all students' name in one dropdown.